# Kendo Grid Hierarchy templating issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My design requires a checkbox as the first column in the grid and subsequent grids, however, using Hierarchy to implement those subsequent grids, the drop down arrow that kendo adds becomes the first column making the column with the checkbox template second. Is there an efficient / official way of getting around this?

Comment: why do you need the checkbox in the first column?

Comment: it's a visual design to select the current item on that row